# Isn't the current trend of young, unmarried, women living at home merely a reversion to older practices?

Tags: world-war-two, cultural-history, women

The trend of Millenials "boomeranging" home, or never leaving in the first place is much-reported-upon, and much lamented, [here](http://www.reuters.com/article/2015/11/11/us-usa-women-relatives-idUSKCN0T01X820151111), for example.

Is this a new trend, or merely a reversion to pre-WWII customs (the link cites 1940 as a comparable circumstance)? I agree that delaying marriage, per se, was not part of the practice, but wasn't it typical for unmarried women (I'm peeling off young men from this question) to live with their families?

As a user noted below, obviously the article confirms the statistical fact here; I'm looking for a broader historical context.

Comment: Doesn't that article already answer this question? *"[In 1940] 36.2 percent of young women lived with relatives ... Among young men, 42.8 percent were living with relatives last year, below the 1940 high of 47.5 percent. 'The result is a striking U-shaped curve for young women - and young men - indicating **a return to the past**, statistically speaking.'"* What are you asking?

Comment: I'd say that the article is one data point, which sparked my interest. I guess I'm asking for a broader historical context that the article hints at.

Comment: Can you update the question to indicate that you're looking for broader historical context, rather than simple confirmation of the statistical fact?

Comment: Why do you mean by "old costumes"? Do you think they are waiting for some guy to marry them so the man can bring income and the woman handles home & the kids? How would fit in that scenario that 27% of young women are enrolled in university, and that they delayed marrying? Have you read and understood the article you linked?

Comment: Customs, not costumes....And the question carefully avoids the interpretation, it merely asks whether unmarried women living at home is a cultural norm. Is there a norm? What is the norm? What are the causes of the U shaped curve?

Comment: @SJuan76 - "old costumes"? Have you read and understood the question you linked? ;)

Comment: Either way, the article already gives you enough data that shows that (in case there is any doubt), the current situation is not at all like the one at the 40s. If you want an explanation of why that statistic is increasing again, you are asking for a sociological answer which is not within the scope of the site.

Comment: It's interesting - I'm getting a really strong "you shouldn't ask this" vibe from you @SJuan76.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the US? A similar trend is occurring in the UK, but that is largely due to housing costs v salaries. No idea if this applies in the US.

Comment: Chris, @SJuan76 is making a very valid point here. You need to elaborate on what exactly you are looking here, that isn't already answered by the article. What does "broader historical context" mean?